# Передача данных через ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".add").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'index.php',
        data: {"test": "test"},
      success: function() {
        alert("Круто");
      },
       error:  function(){
        alert("Не круто");
       }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">Отправить</button>
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

При клике на кнопку отправляется вот такой ajax запрос, но почему то после отправки глобальный массив post как был пустым, так и остался.
Весь код выполняется на одной странице, то есть через ajax я отправляю данные на эту же страницу.

Comment: Ну так вы ничего не делаете с ответом, поэтому "...как был пустым, так и остался"

Comment: Не пойму что значит ничего не делаю с ответом. Насколько я понял, я отправляю данные на главную страницу методом post, по идее у меня в нем должно было что-то появиться

Comment: Где что по вашему должно появиться - на "index.php" или на текущей странице?

Comment: текущая страница это и есть index.php. На ней я распечатываю массив post через var_dump и он пуст

Comment: Страница со скриптом отправляет данные сама на себя

Comment: Похоже вы не понимаете как работает [AJAX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)

Comment: Не отрицаю, подскажите в чем я ошибаюсь

Comment: Просто почитайте статью по ссылке, она не такая большая

Comment: Эта статья никак не ответила на мой вопрос

Comment: "Я ниче не понимаю, сделайте чтобы работало"

Comment: Где вы смотрите результат работы var_dump?

Comment: На этой же странице

Comment: У вас тут нет никакого кода, который отобразил бы результат работы на этой же странице. У вас есть только `alert("Круто")` и больше ничего.

Comment: Тогда следующий вопрос - с чего бы на этой странице появились какие-то новые данные?

Comment: Не было перезагрузки, поэтому не с чего

Comment: @АндрейСивцов вот вы сами и ответили на свой вопрос.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Comment: https://adminnotes.info/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-php-ajax-mysql.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Не выводишь ответ:

success: function(data){ 
  alert( "Прибыли данные: " + data ); 
}
```